# Git commit hash affects Visual Studio dll/exe binary for new format csproj

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, csproj, deterministic

I have many NET Framework projects. Old projects have old csproj format with Deterministic=true. So whenever I build assembly I receive binary the same output file (dll or exe). New projects have new csproj format. In new format there is no Deterministic option. The most strange thing is that current checkout git hash affects output binary file. So I receive the same binary only for the same git commit. But if I change something that does not affects project and build it I am getting different binary.

The simplest way to reproduce:

1. Build project
2. Change git commit message to any other (or even the same) via git `commit --ammend -m "Some message"`
3. Build project
4. Compare binaries (they differs)

I want my binaries to be identical if project is identical no matter from which git commit it was build (the same as it was with old csproj format). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that one of referenced project (lets call it 'SomeProject') used Nerdbank.GitVersioning to generate file version. Which is why all projects that depends on 'SomeProject' binaries were changing upon build.